# Dynamics of Binary Process

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Consider a vector $m \in \{-1,1\}^n$ and, given $m$, consider the set $H(m) = \{h \in \{0,1,-1\}^{n-1}: h_i \in \{0,m_i\}\}$.

These objects may be interpreted as a set of binary messages $(m_1,..,m_n)$ and an history of reports $h \in H(m) $observed at period N.
The n-th element of the history of reports is $m_n$ with probability $P_n(h(m),m)$ and $0$ otherwise. This holds for all $i \in \{2,..,n\}$, while $h_1 = m_1$ with probability 1.

$P_n(h(m),m)$ depends, as per notation, on the history, which is constrained by the message $m$, and can be defined as:
$$ P_n(h(m),m) = (1 - (1-H)^{k(h)}(1-L)^{l(h)}), $$
with $H$ and $L$ being problem parameters, such that $H,L \in (0,1)$ and $H > L$, $k = |\{h_i \in h: h_i = m_n \}|$ and, viceversa, $l=|\{h_i \in h: h_i \neq m_n \}|$.

What I am interested in is the expected value of this probability over all possible histories, given $m$:
$$ P_n(m) = \mathbb{E}_h[P_n(h(m),m)] = \sum_{h \in H_i(m)} \underset{\text{Probability of $h$ happening}}{\underbrace{\prod_{j \in A(h)} P_j (m) \prod_{j \notin A(h)} (1 - P_j(m))}} (1 - (1 - L)^{l(h)}(1-H)^{k(h)}), $$

with $A(h) = \{j \in \{1,..,n-1\}: h_j = m_n\}$.

More specifically I am interested in showing that $P_n(m \mid m_1 = m_n) > P_n(m \mid m_1 \neq m_n)$ for all $m$ and $n$ and all specifications of $H,L$.

So far, I tried to show this by induction, but with no success. The induction hypothesis would be that $P_i (m \mid m_1 = m_i) > P_i (m \mid m_1 \neq m_i)$ for all $i \leq n$.
I also tried to find a counterexample numerically, but the problem is that I did not find a way to write this process in an iterative way in code, so I have to write down the cases by hand. Anyhow, up to $n=4$ the statement holds.

In terms of narrative, to visualize the problem better, the idea is that a message $m$ is drawn from some distribution and, in each period $i$, the i-th piece of the message is revealed and added to the history (is "reported") with some probability or not revealed (and 0 is added). Indeed, it can be seen in the expression for $P_n(h(m),m)$ that if a 0 is part of the history of reports, it has no impact on the reveal probability.
What I want to check is if the impact on the first bit of report ($m_1$) grows going down the chain.

Any help is very much appreciated.